# Can't Play 3 Animations on one Object Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to play 3 animations on a cube, when a condition is checked the first animation should be played, then when the second condition is checked, the second animation, and the same thing for the last one.

So I've created 3 animations and make them as legacy, then I attached animation component to the cube, and add the animations to it. The problem I have with the script below is that the first animation works fine, but the 2 rest didn't. What should I do to fix that?

```
Animation CubeRot;
    bool Rot = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        CubeRot = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (FindObjectOfType<HoseController>().Rotated1 == true)
        {
            if (!Rot)
            {
                CubeRot.Play("Rot1");
                Rot = true;
            }
        }
        if (FindObjectOfType<HoseController>().Rotated2 == true)
        {
            if (!Rot)
            {
                CubeRot.Play("Rot2");
                Rot = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In general: Do **not** use `FindObjectOfType` repeatedly. Rather store the reference once and reuse it like `private HoseController hoseController; private void Start() { hoseController = FindObjectOfType<HoseController>();  }` and then everywhere only use e.g. `if(hoseController.Rotated1){ ... }`

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because you are setting `Rot = true;` in the first update. Then the second update requires the `Rot` variable to be `false` but its still true from the 1st update?

Answer (score 1):

First:
You require Rot to be false in both if.

Second:
If Rotated1 is true the first part will loop (since you are in the Update) and since you do not set it to false in your if it will continue to loop.
You can even avoid to use both Rotated1 and Rot

Also you should try to avoid the legacy animation component. It should be easy to do the same behaviour in the new Animator component

Finally avoid to use FindObjectOfType each time